# Passing value from one class to another, using @property

Tags: objective-c, class, variables

I have been pulling my hair out all afternoon trying to figure out why the following code will not work.  All I am trying to do is pass a string, from one class to another.

In my FirstDetailViewController.h file I declare the NSString

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *infoForArray;
```

And then in my Grinding01_DetailViewController.m I try to set a value for the string

```
#import "Grinding01_DetailViewController.h"
#import "FirstDetailViewController.h"

@implementation Grinding01_DetailViewController


...

    NSString *didLoadMessage = @"Grinding01 Loaded";

    FirstDetailViewController *temp = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailView" bundle:nil];

    temp.infoForArray = didLoadMessage;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES];

}
```

When I output the infoForArray from the FirstDetailViewController.h it is null.

Any help would be appreciated, I think there's a simple step that I am missing, but I just can't see it.

---

EDIT:  Here is the code from the FirstDetailViewController

FirstDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Protocols.h"

@interface FirstDetailViewController : UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> {

    //for the output
    IBOutlet UITextView *outputView;

    UIToolbar *navigationBar;

    NSMutableArray *logMessages;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *navigationBar;

//for incoming messages
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *infoForArray;


@end
```

FirstDetailViewController.m

```
#import "FirstDetailViewController.h"

@implementation FirstDetailViewController

@synthesize navigationBar, infoForArray;

-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //The log cannot be changed
    outputView.editable = NO;    

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.navigationBar = nil;

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    NSLog(@"message: %@", infoForArray);

    outputView.text = infoForArray;

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Managing the popover

- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    // Add the popover button to the toolbar.
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [navigationBar.items mutableCopy];
    [itemsArray insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
    [navigationBar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];
    [itemsArray release];
}


- (void)invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    // Remove the popover button from the toolbar.
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [navigationBar.items mutableCopy];
    [itemsArray removeObject:barButtonItem];
    [navigationBar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];
    [itemsArray release];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Rotation support

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc {
    [navigationBar release];
    [super dealloc];
}   


@end
```

Comment: Are you synthesizing the infoForArray property at the top of your FirstDetailViewController implementation?

Comment: Yepp, `@synthesize navigationBar, infoForArray;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the trouble area is in in FirstDetailViewController. I would suggest posting the code for that so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see the issue, so I made a program similar to yours but mine does indeed show the message. The only thing that jumps out at me is the name of the XIB file. Generally when I load from a XIB the name matches the view controller name, as in, you would be loading from @"FirstDetailViewController" instead of @"FirstDetailView". Is it possible you have multiple XIBs lying around and that you are using one with an Outlet named info message, which is blasting the value you are trying to set?

Comment: The FirstDetailViewController .h and .m files were already created for me, along with the FirstDetailView.xib (I started with some apple sample code).  I will try changing the names around and see what happens.  Edit just tried it and still nothing.  I think I might just start over (laughs) and see what happens

Comment: Probably not a bad idea. If you are interested in the exact cause though, please zip it all up and send it to me or put it up somewhere for download and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Creating a new project solved the problem, I think that the problem may have had something to do with the fact that I had changed some of the file names.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've been there myself. If your project gets to any sort of decent size though, starting a new one isn't a viable option. So next time you hit a snag, just hang in there and work it through! :)

Answer (score 0):

my guess is you are checking for infoForArray somewhere in the instantiation process of FirstDetailViewController, which occurs before you set `temp.infoForArray = didLoadMessage`.

Just for reference, if you check for `infoForArray` in `viewDidLoad` that will be too early. **`viewDidLoad` is triggered when the view is put into memory. What you want is `viewDidAppear`**, which you may have to add yourself

Comment: I am checking for it in the `viewDidLoad()` method of my FirstDetailViewController

Comment: Check in viewwillappear or viewdidappear and see then

Comment: @HelloWorld so when you step through Grinding01_DetailViewController, do you see infoForArray being set? I'm still betting that you are checking it before it's set. Like ChrisH says, viewDidAppear is probably the right spot for you

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I just tried implementing that, and still got infoForArray as NULL.